# rbind data frames only for same columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have 24 data frames that I need to combine. 20 data frames have the same 238 columns, instead 4 data frames have 256 columns. Moreover, the 4 data frames with 256 columns have a different order of columns compared to the other 20 data frames.

E.g. 'answer', 'condition', 'msg_time', 'fix', etc. (20 data frames)

E.g. 'acc_value', 'nitem', 'fix', 'button_press_0', 'rotation', 'previous_fix', 'accuracy', 'answer','file', 'condition', etc. (4 data frames)

I would like to rbind only those columns that are the same in all 24 data frames.
Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package, `rbindlist` from `data.table` or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
df <- data.frame()            # empty data.frame
base_names <- names(a)        # base_names will reflect any data.frame that has 238 observations
list_df <- list(a, b, c)      # list of all your data frames

for(item in list_df){         # create loop

  items <- item[, base_names] # only select columns that match the 238 columns
  df <- rbind(df, items)      # append those to the data.frame

}

df                            # all data.frames rbinded
```

---

If you want to avoid loops, you can also use lapply

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 

df <- data.frame()
base_names <- names(a)
list_df <- list(a, b, c)  

lapply(list_df,
       function(x){

         x_cols <- x[, base_names]
         df <- rbind(df, x_cols)

       }) %>% plyr::ldply(rbind)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @maloneypatr. I've tried both your solutions. However, for the loop, I get this error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(item, , base_names) : undefined columns selected". For the second solution, is there a reason why you used "%>%"? Because it gives an error. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why, but I changed 'item' with 'items', and 'items' into 'dataframes' and now the loop works. It takes a while, but it works fine! :) Thank you.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I use the `%>%` from the `dplyr` package.  I'll edit the code to reflect