# 'invalid factor level, NA generated' for which columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, na, rbind

This is an extension of the previous question:

[rbind data frames only for same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123494/rbind-data-frames-only-for-same-columns/33123981?noredirect=1#comment54065418_33123981)

I managed to append my data frames into a new data frame, but now I get this warning message.

> Warning messages:
>   1: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, ri, value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated
>   2: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, ri, value = c(150L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

I understand that I should convert the factor variables into character variables before using rbind, with something like:

```
Mydf[sapply(Mydf, is.factor)] <- lapply(Mydf[sapply(Mydf, is.factor)], as.character)
```

But is there a way to understand which columns I need to convert? Or should I convert all those variables that are factors into character?
I have 238 columns for each of 24 data frames, and I assume I need to convert all or some factor variables in each data frame.

Any suggestion about how to proceed?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think rbind can properly bind two columns with one as factor and another as character. Your problem is probably caused by rbind a factor column and a numeric (integer) column.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your comment. So, if that is the case, still the question is how I can find which columns are creating the problem? Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Choose two of your data frames that cause the problem. And find two columns with the same name (one is numeric and another is factor, use the "class" function) in the two data frames. I may find a solution for your problem. Use the rbind.fill function in the plyr package. See the following code. 
df1 <- data.frame(V1=1:3, V2=c("A", "B", "A"));
df2 <- data.frame(V1=4:6, V2=3:1);

rbind(df1, df2);

library(plyr);
rbind.fill(df1, df2);